# Ansible syntax error in task

Tags: ansible

This code was working fine in 1.7.  I updated to 1.8 and now I get a syntax error.

This is the code in the nagios_iptables.yml

```
---
- name: get iptables rules
  shell: iptables -L
  register: iptablesrules
  always_run: yes
  changed_when: false

- name: add nagios iptables port 5666
  command: /sbin/iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 5666 --source 192.168.1.59 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "nagios"
  when: iptablesrules.stdout.find("nagios") == -1

- name: add nagios iptables port 5666 localhost
  command:/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 5666 --source 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "nagios"
  when: iptablesrules.stdout.find("nagios") == -1

- name: save iptables
  command: service iptables save

- name: restart iptables
  service: name=iptables state=restarted
```

This is how I call it:

```
- include: tasks/nagios_iptables.yml
```

This is the syntax error I get:

> ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script,
>
> .../playbooks/tasks/nagios_iptables.yml
>
> Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 14,
>   column 3
>
> command:/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 5666 --source
>   127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "nagios"   when: iptablesrules.stdout.find("nagios") == -1

I have no idea what the problem is, hopefully it's something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this turned out to be something obvious.

However, it's fairly insidious.

The problem was a missing space on this line:

```
command:/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 5666 --source 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "nagios"
```

The lack of a space between the `command:` and the `/sbin/iptables` causes the problem.

This seems to be a new restriction in 1.8, or maybe I'm going crazy.

Comment: According to wikipedia, the YAML format *requires* the space after the colon: "Keys are separated from values by a colon+space." So if it worked previously, that was the bug, not how it behaves now. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Associative_arrays

Comment: Looks like a "we fixed the bug", that's why it doesn't work any more, situation.  Fair enough.